# Trigger event on tile layer

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to make a click event occur only on the tile layer on a Leaflet map?

I tried

```js
var tiles= L.tileLayer(...).addTo(map);

tiles.on('click', function(e) { console.log('ok') });
```

but it doesn't do anything. I also tried

```js
tiles.on({ click: console.log('ok') });
```

but it only triggers once when the map loads.

I'd like this event to occur only on tile layers, not when the user clicks on another layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a click event occur only on the tile layer on a Leaflet map?

No.

If you read the [documentation for `L.TileLayer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#tilelayer), you'll see that `L.TileLayer`s do **not** have a `click` event.

> I'd like this event to occur only on tile layers, not when the user clicks on another layer.

If that's the case, then you should look at attaching a `click` event handler to the `L.Map` instance, and use [`L.DomEvent.stopPropagation`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#domevent-stoppropagation) on any other `click` event handlers (so that e.g. a marker click event won't propagate upwards to the map instance and fire the map's `click` event handler).